# What's the meaning of confidence in android sniff method?

Tags: android, android-ndk

all:

In DataSource::sniff method to get confidence value.
So what the meaning of confidence? How to understand it?
When it's value is greater or equal 0.6f, means found the sniff. But in SniffMP3 function, the confidence is set to 0.2f. Why?

```
    bool DataSource::sniff(
        String8 *mimeType, float *confidence, sp<AMessage> *meta) {
    *mimeType = "";
    *confidence = 0.0f;
    meta->clear();

    Mutex::Autolock autoLock(gSnifferMutex);
    for (List<SnifferFunc>::iterator it = gSniffers.begin();
         it != gSniffers.end(); ++it) {
        String8 newMimeType;
        float newConfidence;
        sp<AMessage> newMeta;
        if ((*it)(this, &newMimeType, &newConfidence, &newMeta)) {
            if (newConfidence > *confidence) {
                *mimeType = newMimeType;
                *confidence = newConfidence;
                *meta = newMeta;
                if(*confidence >= 0.6f) {
                    LOGV("Ignore other Sniffers - confidence = %f , mimeType = %s",*confidence,mimeType->string());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return *confidence > 0.0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it will just look for the best parser for the file. if

```
((*it)(this, &newMimeType, &newConfidence, &newMeta))
```

returned true, it is already a parser for that file. But, there might be a case that there are more than 1 parser for that file so it will just look for the best.